# Encodings get messed up when writing to file

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm downloading some html files from the web in different encodings (which I know beforehand) and I need to write them to a file encoded as `UTF-8`.
Some stuff is omitted for brevity:

```
try {
    url = new URL(urlString);
    is = url.openStream();
    buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, charset));
    while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
    ...
} finally {
    ...
}
return text.toString();
```

If all strings in Java are encoded as `UTF-16`, then this should read the whole page as the charset (e.g. `windows-1252`) and store it in the `String` object (in this case a `StringBuilder`) re-encoded as `UTF-16`.

Now I write the exact same string to a file:

```
File file = new File(savePathHtml + filename);
try {
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, text, "utf-8");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    logger.error(ex);
}
```

When opening the file, there's some gibberish and extra symbols, indicating that the encoding is somehow messed up (e.g. `&nbsp;` turns into `Ä&nbsp;`).

Have I misunderstood how encoding works when working with files or strings?

Comment: Have you implemented FileUtils class or is from some library? In the first case please add the code.

Comment: Are you sure that the source of the HTML page is actually UTF-8? Doesn't look like it is

Comment: It's the `Apache Commons IO` library.

Comment: Off topic: using readLine and simply appending the line you lose the "/n" char.

Comment: The source is not `UTF-8`, that's the problem I'm trying to solve. I get the non-`UTF-8`file and have to save it as `UTF-8`.

Comment: If you print text before saving it, it is visualized correctly?

Comment: Is your text editor opening the file as UTF-8?

Comment: OffTopic: if you are using `apache-commons`, than it is preferred to read stream using `IOUtils.toString(...stream...,...encoding...)` method

Comment: Can you give us an example url with expected encoding?

Comment: It opens as `UTF-8`, but even if I open it as the other encoding, it still contains gibberish.

Comment: Also, when I print the text to System.out while reading in, it's correct.

Comment: The code looks correct. Can you try to read the file again using Java instead of a text editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that none of the text editors can correctly identify the encoding when opening downloaded files.

If I open the file and select the encoding as `UTF-8`, everything looks fine.